# How to perform string concatenation in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, string, plsql, concatenation

I have a variable defined as

```
define dbs '&1'
```

Suppose I pass `database1` as an argument. Then the statement is interpreted as

```
define dbs database1
```

I want to append single quotes around the string, ie I want it to be interpreted as

```
define dbs 'database1'
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Single quotes in strings need to be escaped with another single quote, so you would write (if I understand macro expansion correctly)

```
 '''&1'''
```

String concatenation is done with the || operator

```
 '''' || '&1' || ''''
```